# Determine whether the time is UTC or EST

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have the var `date = new Date()`
by this date I want to get EST or UTC date.
Problem is how to determine either it is be EST or UTC ?

Comment: whether .......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: Try `(new Date).toString().split('(')[1].slice(0, -1)`

Comment: Javascript Dates are UTC, however *toString* typically returns a value adjusted for the host timezone.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getUTCDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

> The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and
>   local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the
>   local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead. For example,
>   if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600
>   will be returned. Daylight saving time prevents this value from being
>   a constant even for a given locale.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

You may also wish to look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) for a friendly API for timezones.